# How to design a load

Tags: led, power, voltage-regulator

Requirements:
I need to design a load that will be powered with 1-4 supplies at any given time. The design requirements are merely that if 1 or more supplies are 'on', there needs to be at least 1 Amp draw from EACH supply.

Application:
Each supply will drive it's own LED. These LEDs draw an extremely low amount of amperage compared to standard LEDs that I'm used to.

If I need to choose different parts, for example, a MOSFET with a smaller Vgs... then I can easily do that. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do with the load. It needs to handle up to 4 amps and as low as 1 amp while keeping steady voltage applied to the LED rail.

The capacitor is designed to delay voltage to the gate of the MOSFET by at least 2ms.

[image]

LM338 dropout voltage ~2V minimum

If the supply is at 12V for all 4, the maximum voltage after the diode is 8.5V. So I design the load to be 2 Ohms to ensure 4 amps of draw total. But with this same load, if there is only 1 supply on at a time and its limited to 1A, the voltage across the load will be only 2V, and this is not enough to power the LEDs. This would also mean a large voltage drop across the current regulator.

What can i do to clean this up/make it work as desired? (This was designed from scratch by me). There may be ICs or components out there that are already made to do what I'm wanting, and I'm not the most experienced with these things yet.

I know I'm going to need forced air, so I wanted to include that in the load.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about using a single LM338 regulator (can take up to 5A) and replacing the large capacitor with RC network?

Comment: Will that single LM338 regulator pull equal amounts of current from all power supplies? Its imperative that each supply, when on, get at least 1 amp of draw.

Comment: What is the benefit of using an RC network instead of just a single cap? I am wanting the cap to draw the 1 amp for the 2ms delay on gate voltage.(I have my reasons :D )

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve. Forget mention of loads - what is your project trying to do?

Comment: The project is to Power LEDs specific to each supply. The specific purpose supplies have safety checks that measure output current. If this current drops below 1A, the outputs shut off. Space requirements determine that I need to dissipate this extra power through a single load no matter how many supplies are on at a time. 1-4

Comment: brett, take a step back and indulge me. What are you trying to make; what's the name of this thing? Why do you use three supplies? What purpose do the leds have?

Comment: Have you try some low dropout regulators?

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT you will get what you want by using a shunt regulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feVxhV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A shunt regulator works by drawing more current from the input supply if the load does not need that current. So it's easy to ensure a minimum load on the input. The current is set by (V<sub>in</sub>-V<sub>reg</sub>)/R1. You'd choose R1 based on the minimum input voltage to ensure your minimum load current.

You would do this separately for each of your inputs rather than for all 4 at once.

This solution also saves you having to find a giant capacitor to absorb 1 A while you're waiting for the load to kick in.

If the input voltage rises to 14.5 V, the shunt will sink more current; 1.3 A for the circuit I drew.

Finding (or designing) a shunt regulator able to sink 1-2 A is left as an excercise for the reader.

Comment: I found an article giving a design for a shunt regulator they claim is capable of up to 8 A: http://electronicdesign.com/analog/high-current-low-voltage-shunt-regulator

Comment: Something to revise that I did not state was that each of my inputs has a possibility to be sourced from 3 different supplies. So, I have a total of 12 possible supplies but only 4 can be on at a time. Think of each of the '4' inputs as a 3 light signal head (4x3=12). Red, Yellow, and Green. Only one color is on at a time so thats why I designed my load for 4 supplies on. However there is a chance that only 1 supply is on. When this happens, I don't get enough voltage to the LEDs.

Comment: Take your circuit and instead of a single supply, use 3. Does it still do the same operation? while 1 supply is ON, the other two supplies will be doing 'lamp checks'. What this consists of is them turning on for 2ms and checking to make sure at least 1Amp of current is drawn. If this passes, the computer knows it's still a good lamp. The circuit that I'm designing is meant to trick the computer into thinking there is a light bulb as the load.

Comment: @bretts, build one of these for each of your supplies. If you want to clarify your requirements, please update your question so that new answers will be able to answer based on all your requirements, not just the ones you put in the question initially.